# All posts and pages without template redirect to index

Tags: wordpress

I have to do some work on older version wp site (4.3) whenever I create a new page and try to access it always give me front page. Other old pages are using templates and they are displayed fine but I need to have a page without a template. What should I look at to find the problem in order to be able to create a new page?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the mechanish fallback of wordpress. In order to have a theme you just need two files index.php and style.csc. see about template hierachy.

If you need a new page you must:
1) create a file page-.php in the folder of using theme
2) from the Gui of wordpress create new page with title

then if you write the proper html/css you are going to see the template that you have created

Comment: Yeah, but what about the posts? they all redirect to the index as well and I need them

Comment: Like he said, look into template hierarchy. Posts will look for single.php before falling back to index - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: #Single Post
The single post template file is used to render a single post. WordPress uses the following path:

single-{post-type}-{slug}.php – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post., WordPress would look for single-product-dmc-12.php.
single-{post-type}.php – If the post type is product, WordPress would look for single-product.php.
single.php – WordPress then falls back to single.php.
singular.php – Then it falls back to singular.php.
index.php  WordPress ultimately falls back to index.php.